# How to inject the currentUser into all other User Models

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

in my application I have several Users that can be friends. Now I am trying to build a function that gets the "friendShipStatus" from the current logged in user to another User.
This is a follow up question from this one: [Intersection of promises and dependent computed properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843337/intersection-of-promises-and-dependent-computed-properties/20845769?noredirect=1#comment31325122_20845769)

```
 /**
 *  Gives the relation between two User
 *  4: has requested your friendship
 *  3: Yourself
 *  2: Friends
 *  1: FriendShip Request
 */
friendShipStatus: function() {
        return this.container.lookup('user:current').then(function(user){
            if(this.get('friends').contains(user)){
                return 2;
            } else if(this.get('friendsWithMe').contains(user)){
                return 4;
            } else if(this.get('myFriends').contains(user)){
                return 1;
            } else if (this.get('id') === user.get('id')){
                return 3;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        });

}.property('friends.@each')
```

The Promise stuff is already an attempt, but not working. I would rather prefer to have the currentUser injected and observe then the property, that as soon as the current user is resolved the property changes. My attempt therefore:

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: "currentUser",

  initialize: function(container, application) {
    var store = container.lookup('store:main');
    container.register('user:current', store.find('user', 1), { instantiate: false, singleton: true });
  }
});

Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: "injectCurrentUser",
  after: 'currentUser',

  initialize: function(container) {
    // container.injection('controller:application', 'currentUser', 'user:current');
    container.typeInjection('route', 'currentUser', 'user:current');
    container.typeInjection('controller', 'currentUser', 'user:current');
    container.typeInjection('model', 'currentUser', 'user:current');
    container.injection('user:model', 'currentUser', 'user:current');
  }
});
```

I have already tried it with a type injection and a regular injection. But within my usermodel my currentUser property is always undefined.

How can I inject the current User into my User Model?

Answer (score 3):

You're not waiting for the user to be returned from ember data before registering. You'll probably want to defer readiness to block until it's back. Try something like this:

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: "currentUser",

  initialize: function(container, application) {
    application.deferReadiness();
    container.lookup('store:main').find('user', 1).then(function(user) {
      application.register('user:current', user, { instantiate: false, singleton: true });
      application.inject('route', 'currentUser', 'user:current');
      application.inject('controller', 'currentUser', 'user:current');
      application.advanceReadiness();
    }, function() {
      application.advanceReadiness();
    });
  }
});
```

I'm not sure why you'd want to inject into your model, route/controller is sufficient in my case. Also note this is one initializer rather than two.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, good stuff. However, it seems that the store is not available when this runs. Do you know if there is a way to defer running the initializer?

Comment: FYI, I just posted another solution below.

Answer (score 3):

Just figured out another solution using ember-cli's services. First generate a service `ember g service user`. Then inject the `store` onto the service so you can do the `find()`. Next change your service from a standard `Object` to `ObjectProxy`. Finally on `init()` do the find and set the result to `content`. Here is what I have in the end:

```
// app/initializers/user-service.js
export function initialize(container, application) {
    application.inject('route', 'user', 'service:user');
    application.inject('controller', 'user', 'service:user');
    application.inject('service:user', 'store', 'store:main');
}

export default {
    name: 'user-service',
    initialize: initialize
};
```

.

```
// app/services/user.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectProxy.extend({
    init: function(){
        this.set('content', this.store.find('user', 1));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding model injection, it is in fact possible, see the answer here

[Injecting dependencies into an Ember model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068890/injecting-dependencies-into-an-ember-model/24075950#24075950)