# Injecting dependencies into an Ember model

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm attempting to inject dependencies into my Ember models.

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/3670, states that this is disabled. Following a link to https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/blob/master/blueprint/app/app.js#L4 demonstrates how to enable `MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS`, which in theory, should allow me to inject dependencies into my models, however I'm having no luck.

In the absence of this solution, are there other ways to inject a ref to an app-wide, global singleton object into an Ember.Model besides just dumping it onto the app's namespace (ie. App.ImAGlobalconfig`)?

for reference, this is the initializer I'm working on

```
App.initializer({
  name: 'preload',
  initialize: function(container/*, application*/) {
    App.deferReadiness();

    Ember.$.ajax({
      url: CONFIG.configURL,
      dataType: 'json',
      context: this
    }).done(
      function(json/*,status, request*/) {
       var appConfig;

        // ...

        container.register('app:config', appConfig, {instantiate: false});
        container.injection('controller', 'appConfig', 'app:config');
        container.injection('route', 'appConfig', 'app:config');
        container.injection('view', 'appConfig', 'app:config');
        container.injection('model', 'appConfig', 'app:config'); // I don't work!

        App.advanceReadiness();
      }
    ).fail(
      function(status, request, error) {
        console.log('Unable to load config with: ' + error);
      }
    );
  }
});
```

Thanks for any and all help/opinions.

Comment: at the heart of it, this is essentially the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952274/how-to-inject-the-currentuser-into-all-other-user-models?rq=1 which has gone unanswered. Just saw that post, so I'm happy to delete this one if need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model injections does indeed work:

```
Ember.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS = true;    
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.initializer({
  name: 'model-injection',

  initialize: function(container, application) {

    var cfg = {version: '1'};
    container.register('app:config', cfg, {instantiate: false});


    container.injection('model', 'cfg', 'app:config');
    App.advanceReadiness();
  }
});

App.deferReadiness();
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lomiy/1/edit

Comment: Ah, you are correct, we are using a 1.4.x canary build (due to some the ever changing, not yet integrated, 'params' api) apparently model injection is not present in that build, but it is now (or at least in the 1.7.x canary builds). I think in the future, I'll try a POC approach against the current canary builds. Thanks!