# Injecting dependencies into an 'ember-model' Model and use of the MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS flag

Tags: ember.js, ember-model

I previously asked a similar question here [Injecting dependencies into an Ember model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068890/injecting-dependencies-into-an-ember-model), but I now believe my issue is really around injection of dependencies into an 'ember-model' model.

Even when I have set `Ember.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS = true`, I cannot seem to inject deps into my models that are constructed with `Ember.Model`.

I have created a jsbin http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yizoyozu/4/edit?html,js,console,output which demonstrates injection working for routes, views, and controllers, but not for models.

the code is something akin to:

```
Ember.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS = true;

App = Ember.Application.create();

App.initializer({
  name: 'config',
  initialize: function(container) {
    App.deferReadiness();
    container.register('app:config', {foo: 'bar', baz: 'boom'}, {instantiate: false});
    container.injection('model', 'appConfig', 'app:config');
    container.injection('controller', 'appConfig', 'app:config');
    container.injection('route', 'appConfig', 'app:config');
    container.injection('view', 'appConfig', 'app:config');
    App.advanceReadiness();
  }
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.Colors = Ember.Model.extend({
  color: Ember.attr(),
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    console.log('inside aModel', this.appConfig); // does this not work?
  }
});

App.Colors.load([
  {id: 1, color: 'red'}
]);

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    console.log('inside aRoute', this.appConfig);
    return App.Colors.find(1);
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    console.log('inside aController', this.appConfig);
  }
});
```

with the following templates

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2> Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <ul>

      <li>model.color = {{model.color}}</li>
      <li>model.appConfig =  {{model.appConfig}}</li> <!-- I won't print model.appConfig -->
      <li>view.appConfig.foo = {{appConfig.foo}}</li>

    </ul>
  </script>
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember Model just does `ClassType.create()`  to create instances, it doesn't use the container for instantiating instances.  This means, no DI with Ember Model.  You could attach the container to a base Ember Model, have all of your model's inherit from it, and then attach the appConfig to it.

MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS applies to Ember Data.

Generally I'd avoid recommending hitting the container raw like, but people do what they want to do, so here's how it could be done.

```
App.BaseModel = Ember.Model.extend({
  appConfig: function(){
    return App.__container__.lookup('app:config');
  }.property()
});

App.Cow = App.BaseModel.extend({
  id: Ember.attr(),
  name: Ember.attr()
});
```

http://jsbin.com/fojacoxe/1/edit

Comment: I like the approach you are recommending. But how would one go about attaching the Application's container to an Ember.Model? I see that you  can grab the Application container with `App.buildContainer()`, which appears to return a ref to `App.__container__`, but after that I'm at a loss.

Comment: got it, I was overcomplicating the whole thing. Thanks!